# How to edit the Reddit navigation bar using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make the Reddit navigation bar only display a few subreddits like this:
http://i.imgur.com/eDOdUBJ.png

Using code from another userscript (https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/12571-expand-subreddit-header), I was able to remove the text:

```
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = 
    "#sr-header-area .flat-list > li  { white-space: initial !important; } " + 
    "#sr-header-area .dropdown.srdrop { padding-left: 0 !important; }" +
    ".sr-list                         { display: inline !important; visibility: hidden; } " +
    "#sr-header-area > .width-clip    { position: initial !important; padding-left: 5px !important; } " +
    "#sr-more-link                    { display: none !important; } " +
    ".dropdown.srdrop                 { display: none !important; }";

document.head.appendChild(css);
```

However, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to replace it with text links. The code for the navigation bar with two links looks like this:

```
<div id="sr-header-area">
<div class="width-clip">
<div class="sr-list">
<span class="separator">&nbsp;</span>
<ul class="flat-list sr-bar hover" id="sr-bar">
<li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/" class="choice">AskReddit</a></li>
<li><span class="separator">-</span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/" class="choice">funny</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome dev tools (or Firebug, or similar), use the "Inspect Element" feature to click on an item and find it in the inspection window.

From here, you will be able to see a list of the hierarchy associated to the item, along with identifiers for the item or its parents and siblings.

Look at the screenshot below:

- The first of the Subreddit items is inspected, as shown in the main webpage window by the blue overlay and yellow popup.
- Below the webpage is the inspector. The mouse is hovering over the first Subreddit link, "AskReddit".
- Directly below the HTML is the hierarchy list, showing in blue the selected element, with its parent elements to the left of it in the list, and its child elements to the right.
- Using this view, we can see that the subreddit bar itself has an ID of "sr-bar", and the items you are looking to remove are contained within the "LI" items in the list.

[image: Chrome dev tools - find element]

In JavaScript, we can obtain a reference of the list of subreddits by using `querySelectorAll` and passing in the CSS selector that matches all of the items.

Using a for loop, we can traverse and manipulate the list of subreddits. Below you can see how to loop over all subreddits apart from the first, and remove them from the page.

```
var subredditListItems = document.querySelectorAll("#sr-bar>li");

for(var i = 1, len = subredditListItems.length; i < len; i++) {     
    listOfItems[i].remove();
}
```

It's also possible to manipulate the list in other ways. For instance, it looks like you would benefit from adding or changing list items. Here's an example of how to add my own link there:

```
var subredditListBar = document.querySelectorAll("#sr-bar");
var subredditItem = document.createElement("li");
var link = document.createElement("a");

link.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
link.textContent = "Stack Overflow!";

subredditItem.appendChild(link);
subredditListBar.appendChild(subredditItem);
```

[image: Edited]